# Problem converting time into pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, hour, minute

I am trying to convert a date column containing only hours, minutes and seconds ito a datetime form using pandas.to_datetime(). However, it adds year and date automatically. I also tried using
pandas.to_datetime(df["time"], format = %H:%M:%S").dt.time, again the data type remains object.
Is there any method that can change into datetime format without year and date?

Comment: try [pd._to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

Comment: datetime necessarily has a date… what is your final goal?

Comment: Thank you @mozway. I have solar irradiance data and I want to process the data ( averaging). My data only contains hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Thank you mrbc42. This works perfectly when the original date contains year, date, hour, minute and seconds. In my case where I have only minutes and seconds, it does not work. It adds year , month and day like this: 1900-01-01 14:00:06.

Answer (score 0):

put .dt.time on the end

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore').dt.time
```